# Understanding why a specific algorithm solution works correctly

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, data-structures, return

I'm a beginner in DSA. I'm using Java for practising DSA. Recently I tried to solve a medium level question on leetcode and when my solution exceeded time limit I checked out other people's solutions. However I cannot understand a portion of this solution.

leetcode Question 50) Pow(x,n)

Problem Statement :

Implement pow(x, n), which calculates x raised to the power n (i.e., xn).

Example 1:

```
Input: x = 2.00000, n = 10
Output: 1024.00000
```

Example 2:

```
Input: x = 2.10000, n = 3
Output: 9.26100
```

Example 3:

```
Input: x = 2.00000, n = -2
Output: 0.25000
Explanation: 2-2 = 1/22 = 1/4 = 0.25
```

Constraints:

```
-100.0 < x < 100.0
-231 <= n <= 231-1
n is an integer.
Either x is not zero or n > 0.
-104 <= xn <= 104
```

Solution code (successfully submitted):

```
class Solution 
 {
     public double myPow(double x, int n) 
     {
            //edge case
            if(x == 1 || n == 0)
                return 1;
            if(x == 0) 
                return 0;
            if(x == -1) 
                if (n % 2 == 0)
                    return 1 ;
                else
                    return -1 ;
            if(n == 1) 
                return x;
            
            // use long as -Neg max change to Pos max will overflow
            long N = n;
            if(N < 0) 
            {
                N = -N;
                x = 1/x;
            }
            return p(x, N); 
        }
        
        // for loop solution
    double p(double x, long n) 
        {
        double resisual = 1;
        for(long i = n; i > 1; i = i/2)
            {
        if(i%2 == 1)
                {
                    resisual = resisual * x;
                } 
                x = x * x;
        }
            return resisual*x;
    }
}
```

I can understand the code inside `public double myPow(double x, int n)` function . But cannot understand the latter function double p(double x,long n) :

```
// for loop solution
    double p(double x, long n) 
        {
        double resisual = 1;
        for(long i = n; i > 1; i = i/2)
            {
        if(i%2 == 1)
                {
                    resisual = resisual * x;
                } 
                x = x * x;
        }
            return resisual*x;
    }
```

My doubts are:

1. what is `double resisual = 1;` used for exactly?
2. inside the for loop why is i=i/2 being used and how is it not causing a logical error in calculation?
3. why is this code snippet being used?

```
if(i%2 == 1)
{
    resisual = resisual * x;
}
```

4. `x = x * x` - why is x value changed every time instead of something like ans=ans*x?
5. why are we returning `return resisual*x` ?

Comment: *"1. 2. 3. 4. 5. ..."*: A question on Stack Overflow should be just one question. Now it is too broad.

Comment: Example: 3^9. In the first iteration x=3*3= 3^2. In the second iteration x=9*9 = (3^2)^2. Third iteration x=81*81, etc. Using i/2 tries to get closer to '9' by smaller and smaller steps. `resisual` must be taken into account when the exponent is even because of this rounded `i/2` step.

Comment: DSA means Digital Signature Algorithm, not the name of your course.

Comment: "I'm a beginner in DSA". You shouldn't MUANWU.

Comment: MUANWU?  That's "Make Up Abbreviations No-one Will Understand".

Comment: Or as I always say 'please don't use TLAs here'. @ArfurNarf

Comment: @user207421 sorry for the confusion . I'm quite new to Stack Overflow so I wasn't aware of this and here in high school and University level DSA is used as an abbreviation for Data Structures and Algorithms. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to break down the problem. You have to find out `x^n`. Now, we can have two scenarios,

1. `n` is even i.e. `n = 2k`

```
x^n = x^2k
    = (x^2)^(2k/2)
    = (x^2)^k
```

2. `n` is odd i.e. `n = 2k + 1`

```
x^n = x^(2k+1)
    = x^(2k) * x
    = (x^2)^(2k/2) * x
    = (x^2)^k * x
```

You can see, in both cases the problem reduces to finding the `(x^2)^k`. But in case of `n` being odd, you have to multiply the result of `(x^2)^k` with `x` (Q5). This extra `x` is your `residual`. You will start with multiplicative identity `1`, because if there is no residual, the result would remain `(x^2)^k` (Q1). If `n` is odd, you update the `residual` by multiplying with `x` (Q3).

Now, to the problem of finding `(x^2)^k`. You can see, this is the same problem you began with except `x` is now `x^2` and `n` is now `k` which is `n/2`. I think you can now understand your Q4. You keep doing this until you reach `k = 1`. (`i` in your example)

As `n` is a `long` and `2` is an `int`, `n/2` is basically an Integer Division. Integer division is division in which the fractional part (remainder) is discarded. So, `5/2 = 2`, not `2.5`. I guess that answers Q2.

#### **Example-1**: `5^4`

At the beginning of the loop.

```
residual = 1,
x = 5,
i = 4
```

As, `4` is even the `if` condition would be false. So, after first iteration of the loop

```
residual = 1, 
x = 5 * 5 = 25,
i = 4 / 2 = 2
```

`2` is even, `if` condition would be false. After second iteration of the loop

```
residual = 1, 
x = 25 * 25 = 625, 
i = 2 / 2 = 1
```

As `i > 1` is no longer true, the loop terminates. The return value would be `residual * x = 1 * 625 = 625`

#### **Example-2**: `2^7`

At the beginning of the loop.

```
residual = 1, 
x = 2, 
i = 7
```

As, `7` is odd the `if` condition would be true. So, after first iteration of the loop

```
residual = 1 * 2 = 2, 
x = 2 * 2 = 4, 
i = 7 / 2 = 3
```

`3` is odd, `if` condition would be true. After second iteration of the loop

```
residual = 2 * 4 = 8, 
x = 4 * 4 = 16, 
i = 3 / 2 = 1
```

As `i > 1` is no longer true, the loop terminates. The return value would be `residual * x = 8 * 16 = 128`

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much @RifatRubayatulIslam for taking time to explain it .The explanation was very good and it helped me a lot :)